# Adding total SKU's in WooCommerce new order email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried every plugin possible, and see if I can add the total amount of SKUs in the order for the "New Order" email in WooCommerce but most of the plugins just offer a design customizer not rows, fields, or items, etc.

**I just need to display it at the end of the email "New Order" such as**

**Total SKU's: 123**

Feels like it should be simple but I cannot get my head around it. Possible that any Ninja here would be able to help on this matter?.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce emails give you access to the $order object.

You can then loop through items and count them (references: [WooCommerce: Get Order Info (total, items, etc) From $order Object](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/) and [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide: Emails](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/))

Give this a go:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'bbloomer_count_items' );

function bbloomer_count_items( $order ) {
   echo '<p>Total SKU's: ' . count( $order->get_items( 'line_item' ) ) . '</p>';
}
```